# Error: Program type already present when building project

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-library, facebook-conceal

I'm using an 'aar' library which I created.
In both, my project and the library, there is a dependency implementation of Conceal library (each from its own lib folder).

When I build the project after importing the library and using ProGuard obfuscation, I get this error message:

```
Error: Program type already present: com.facebook.crypto.cipher.NativeGCMCipher
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

this error say you are importing the dependency which already imported in project.

solution :- remove or exclude this dependency

ex:-

```
compile ('com.github.ganfra:material-spinner:1.1.1'){
    exclude group: 'com.nineoldandroids'
  }
```

Comment: I understand that the dependency imported already, but when remove it from the library I can't build because its missing the library, and when I remove it from the project it can't import from the library.
How can I exclude it from the library?

Comment: I'm implementing using a jar file:
    implementation files('libs/conceal_android.jar')
    implementation files('libs/libconceal.jar')

should I write:
implementation files('libs/libconceal.jar') {exclude group: 'com.facebook.crypto.cipher.NativeGCMCipher'}

Comment: @Itay the class name is not the package name; run `./gradlew app:dependencies > dependencies.txt` and add it to the question; then one probably can answer that.

Comment: it gives me an error - "Gradle DSL method not found: 'exclude()' " when I write - "implementation files('libs/libconceal.jar') exclude(group: 'com.facebook.crypto.Conceal') "

Comment: @Itay why would you want to exclude a package from itself? see the above comment.

Comment: I want to exclude it in the library implementation while it still exist in the project implementation.
otherwise I'll get the "Program type already present" error

Answer (score 0):

according to `mavenCentral()`, this is the package name (which could be used instead of `.jar`):

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.facebook.conceal/conceal
implementation "com.facebook.conceal:conceal:2.0.2"
```

therefore the exclusion should look about like this:

```
implementation( project(":libraryproject") ) {
    exclude group: "com.facebook.conceal"
}
```

Comment: I get "Gradle DSL method not found: 'exclude()' " error

Comment: @Itay are you certain to have used the code as displayed? that syntax is correct. if you get any `Gradle DSL method not found: 'exclude()'`, you might be missing the surrounding `()` brackets.

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, the error means that I imported a dependency that already imported in the project (once in the project and once in the library).
The suggested solutions of @Mayur Dabhi and @Martin Zeitler had the right approach, but unfortunately, I wasn't able to get the exclude command working.

finally, with the help of @Martin Zeitler, I replaced:

```
implementation files('libs/conceal_android.jar')
implementation files('libs/libconceal.jar')
```

with:

```
implementation "com.facebook.conceal:conceal:2.0.2"
```

meaning I removed the 'Conceal' jar files from the 'lib' folder and imported the dependency. After that, the error message disappeared and I managed to build the project.

Thanks for anyone who tried to help :)